# Prove that $\frac{t}{3} < Rr$.

Tags: geometry, triangles

The task is:

An optional triangles area should be $t$ and its circumscribed circle radius $=~R$ and its inscribed circles radius $=~r$. Prove that $\frac{t}{3} < Rr$.

I was trying to solve it by calculating the are of the triangle in a different way with heron's formula, but it didn't seem to be a good way to go.

Can you help me solving this problem by telling me the answer an a good desciption, so next time I could solve these kind of problems on my own?

Comment: **Hint:** $t=\dfrac{abc}{4R}=r\dfrac{a+b+c}2$

Comment: @Lucian I still don't manage doing it. It's the same thing I tried.

Comment: We are basically asked to minimize $Rr=\dfrac12\cdot\dfrac{abc}{a+b+c}$ given the conditions $a,b,c>0,~$ $a+b>c,~$ $b+c>a,~$ and $c+a>b$.